# A collection of short stories possibly from 80s. One involved a man who could pass through walls

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There was a book I read about 30 years ago. It was a collection of sci-fi themed short stories. The book title was "I come from Mars" which was also the title of one of those stories. Here are some of the details I can remember:

- One story was about a man who is a normal employee with a jerk boss. One day he discovers that he can pass through walls. He first uses this ability to terrorize his boss, passing through the wall of his room and threatening him. And when the boss comes to check on him, finds out that he is just sitting there doing his job. So the boss implies that he is hallucinating and eventually gets hospitalized in a mental clinic.

  Next, the man finds more creative ways to use this ability and ends up robbing banks. He chooses a pseudonym "Garro Garro" which he writes on a piece of paper and puts everywhere he robs. No one knows this mysterious and highly skilled thief and nothing can stop him. So after Garro Garro becomes a sensation, he gets bored and decides to do bigger jobs. He plans to rob the big pyramid of Giza, but during his passage through the walls of the pyramid, his ability fades away and he gets stuck there forever.
- Another story was about a successful and well-respected man who is about to give a speech to the people of a small town where he lives. During the speech, he confesses that he is actually a Martian. They came to this city some 20 years ago to do a reconnaissance operation and plan for a future attack. But due to some circumstances that I don't remember, he decides to betray his fellow Martians and continue to live in that city. Making a family and gaining the respect of other citizens. The book title was borrowed from this story.
- There was another story that didn't have much of a scifi theme. It was about someone who is doing some charitable work for the people of a city. But actually, he was cleverly planning for the escape of a fellow prisoner and his true intentions are revealed at the end.

It is possible that these stories were ***translated*** from various resources and they are not actually from a single book, but my gut feeling casts a high amount of doubt on this. As I said, I read them some 30 years ago and this is all I can remember. They might be from the 80s or early 90s, but it's also possible that they originate to a much earlier era.

Comment: You know the title of the collection (at least in your language) -- what's the question?  If you're trying to find the book again in its original language, it would help to know where and in what language you *read* the collection.

Comment: @ZeissIkon The question is, I can't find any mention of this book anywhere. It was a Persian/Farsi translation

Comment: This might have been a collection put together in your homeland with stories from various sources, then.  The collection together sound a bit like one of the *Twilight Zone* collections, but at least in English, those always had *Twilight Zone* in the title.

Comment: The "man who walks through walls" story is almost certainly "Le Passe-muraille" (literally "the passer-through-walls") by Marcel Aymé, published in 1941.

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm and "Garro Garro" must be "Garou Garou"

Comment: @ZeissIkon and as it happens, it wasn't the right title, based on the self-answer...

Comment: The ending of *Le Passe-Muraille* traumatized me as a kid (we had this book at school). You can still see M. Dutilleul stuck in the wall [here](https://www.google.com/maps/@48.8874866,2.3379692,3a,75y,58.21h,84.43t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1skBzGPseBqrKu809XB0OyPA!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3DkBzGPseBqrKu809XB0OyPA%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D110.85053%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the book! The problem was, I sticked to searching through English resources. This time I decided to try French ones. Looks like it is definitely ***[15 histoires de science-fiction](https://www.amazon.fr/15-histoires-science-fiction-Bertrand-Solet/dp/2217040715)*** by Bertrand Solet and Francisco Batet. It is actually a collection of 15 short stories from multiple authors.

[Here](https://www.noosfere.org/livres/niourf.asp?numlivre=2146590865) you can find a short review of the book as well as list of the stories (in French). The rough translation says:

> An invisible man, another who passes through the walls, mysterious worlds under the earth and at the bottom of the oceans, trees springing up on the planet Mars, extraordinary inventions, the threat of the Spoq (but who is the Spoq?) ... Science fiction has not finished amazing us. It is not only the fruit of our fertile imagination, but also the reflection of the fears, dreams and hopes of each of us. Fifteen different stories, written by the greatest authors of a genre of novel whose success continues to grow.

Comment: Don't forget to accept in two days. :)